# Using exceptions in Java with user I/O

Tags: java, exception, io

I am trying to do the following: I am making a program in Java which let me create and read text files. So far I have been able to do this, but the hard(?) part is this: I have to be able to get an error when anything else but A, B or C is inside the text file.

So far I got:

```
package textfile;

import java.io.*;
import static java.lang.System.*;

class OutWrite {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try{
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("FAS.txt");
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);

        pw.println("A");
        pw.println("B");
        pw.println("C");

        pw.close();
    } catch (IOException e){
        out.println("ERROR!");
    }
  }   
}
```

And

```
package textfile;

import java.io.*;
import static java.lang.System.*;

class InRead {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("FSA.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        String str;
        while ((str = br.readLine()) != null){
            out.println(str);
        }

        br.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        out.println("File not found");
    }
  }    
}
```

Can anyone steer me in the right direction, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just throw Exception when a new Character is found other than A,B,C .

use,

```
class InRead {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            FileReader fr = new FileReader("FSA.txt");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

            String str;
            while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
                if (str.equals("A") || str.equals("B") || str.equals("c")) //compare
                    out.println(str);
                else
                    throw new Exception(); //throw exception
            }

            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            out.println("File not found");
        }

        catch (Exception e) {//catch it here and print the req message
            System.out.println("New Character Found");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, was taking me ages to figuere out... Not so hard after all!